# On Button Click how to increment counter and show in textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am working on a shopping cart assignment for that I have created a custom ListView that contains the Picture, Price and Add to Cart button in each row. 
I also have a textview at the top which increments everytime the user presses the Add to cart. 
The Button in every row is perfectly working fine but I don't know how to increment the counter and set it to the textview as whenever I do this under onClick event I get runtime error. 
I am sharing with you the code.

```
package uet.cs08.bll;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import uet.cs08.android.R;
import uet.cs08.android.mainActivity2;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class itemBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

 public int count = 5;
 private ArrayList<ItemInfo> itemList;
 private LayoutInflater mInflater;

 public itemBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemInfo> itemList){
     this.itemList=itemList;
     mInflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);

 }
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return itemList.size();

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int idx) {
     return itemList.get(idx);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int idx) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return idx;
}

@Override
public View getView(int idx,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null){

        convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtItemName=(TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
        holder.txtPic=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pic);
        holder.txtPrice=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        holder.counter = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCount);
        Button btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Cart);
        final TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCount);


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 count = Integer.parseInt((String)tv.getText());
                 count++;
                 tv.setText("" + count);


        }
        });
            //tv.setText(""+count);         
            convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else
    {
           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtItemName.setText(itemList.get(idx).itemName);
    holder.txtPic.setImageResource(itemList.get(idx).pic);
    holder.txtPrice.setText(""+itemList.get(idx).price);
    holder.counter.setText(itemList.get(idx).count);

    return convertView;
}


class ViewHolder {
      TextView txtItemName;
      ImageView txtPic;
      TextView txtPrice;
      TextView counter;
     }
```

}
`
**Here is the logCat.**

```
03-20 16:16:38.853: D/AndroidRuntime(2759): Shutting down VM
03-20 16:16:38.853: W/dalvikvm(2759): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
03-20 16:16:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(2759): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 16:16:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(2759): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 16:16:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at uet.cs08.bll.itemBaseAdapter$1.onClick(itemBaseAdapter.java:61)
03-20 16:16:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
03-20 16:16:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
03-20 16:16:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-20 16:16:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-20 16:16:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-20 16:16:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-20 16:16:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 16:16:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-20 16:16:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-20 16:16:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-20 16:16:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: when you have error ,Always post full logcat here and dont forget in future

Comment: Do you have single `TextView` to show counter at the top or in every row?

Comment: It is at the top. I mean it is not repeating in everyrow, but the button is in every row on click on which I want to increment the counter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you have reference to your TextView in xml.

Connect it (using `findViewById()`) inside `onCreate()` of `Activity` only, and you may pass it to your `Adapter` (i.e making a class field and setter getter method), if `Adapter` is a separate class.

and dont do this inside `getView()` of Adapter, remove this line.

```
final TextView tv  = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCount);
```

you will pass your `TextView` from `Activity` to `Adapter` using constructor or setter getter method, will keep a reference using class `Adapter's` class level variable and the what you will do inside `onClick()` of `Button` is:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          count++;
         yourClassLevelTextView.setText(String.valueOf(count));
     }});
```

### EDIT:

how you will pass TextView to Adapter

```
public class YourAdapter extends BlahBlahBlah
{
     private TextView yourClassLevelTextView;
     public void setTextView(TextView textViewFromActivity)
     {
         this.yourClassLevelTextView = textViewFromActivity;
     }
}
```

and in `Activity` do something like this:

```
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(blah, blah, blah);
adapter.setTextView(yourTextViewInActivity);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Under MainActivity class in oncreate function I am now accessing it but I am confused how to set get it and access it in the other class.

Answer (score 2):

Your *tv* `TextView` isn't in the list row layout(where you search for it right now). You'll have to look for it in the activity layout if you declared it there(or in the layout where you declared it):

```
final TextView tv  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I guess count textview in your code not belongs to holder that count text view also should display through holder

Comment: I have tried this but its not working, same error at the same line.

Comment: i think you gave button onclick listener in if(convertview==null) block why can't you check that onclicklistener irrespective of if and else in that convertview place only findviewbyid.can you place the whole code and i will check

Comment: Hello, 
I have edited the question and now the whole code is there. Please have a look thank you,

Answer (score 1):

we have to set value runOnUiThread of that Controls. like this.. May this help you.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    count++;
                   setTimertext(count);

        }
        });

public void setTimertext(String strValue) {         
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                txt.setText(String.valueOf(strValue));    
            }
        });
    }
```