# How many times a button is clicked in Android

Tags: android

I add buttons to my layout file. I want to know how many times my buttons are clicked:

```
if(btn is clicked == 1) {
     then do this
}         
else(btn is clicked > 1) {
  do this     
}
```

How might I approach this?

Comment: add a global variable called clickCounter or something like that and just increment it in the onClickListener. Pretty simple stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this way, first declare global variable on your activity class file like below :

```
int clickcount=0;
```

after add click event to button and increment value `clickcount` variable like below code:

```
    yourbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            clickcount=clickcount+1;
            if(clickcount==1)
            {
                //first time clicked to do this
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button clicked first time!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {

                //check how many times clicked and so on 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button clicked count is"+clickcount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
      count++;
     yourClassLevelTextView.setText(String.valueOf(count));
   }});
```

[Refer this page for more..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785523/on-button-click-how-to-increment-counter-and-show-in-textview)

Answer (score 1):

This exact functionality is used in many of the Android tutorials around the web.[See for example](http://android-helper.blogspot.com.au/2011/04/android-simple-button-click-example.html)

The basic approach is: You need an event handler for your button that updates a field that stores the number of clicks.

Answer (score 0):

for example i use for show an option hidden in my app

```
private LinearLayout linearLayout;
linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_id);


linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickHidden = clickHidden+1;
            if (clickHidden >= 10) {
                linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```