# Index does not update unless the item is being pressed two times in Adapter

Tags: android, listview

For some reason, the variable `mItemIndex` does not update its value until I press the same item for two times.

Yet when I logged both instances of `mItemIndex`, they logged different values. What is wrong here? I've been debugging this for the whole day, yet I can't find the appropriate solution for it.

```
package com.app.burgerking.menu.category.product;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.app.burgerking.R;
import com.app.burgerking.layout.FontHandler;
import com.app.burgerking.models.ModifierGroup;
import com.app.burgerking.models.ModifierItem;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;

/*** Reference to Pass TextView to Adapter: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785523/on-button-click-how-to-increment-counter-and-show-in-textview
***/

public class ModifierGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<ModifierItem> mItems;
    private Typeface berthold;
    private String mModGroupId;

    private TextView tv_totalPrice;
    private TextView tv_totalPrice2;
    private int mItemIndex = -1;

    private TextView tv_availableOptionsCount;
    private ModifierGroup mModGroup;
    private NumberFormat nf;

    // Gregg's Code
    private static final String ACTIVITY = "languageStorage";
    private static String savedLanguage = "";

    private static SharedPreferences spLanguage;
    // End

    public ModifierGridViewAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mItems = new ArrayList<ModifierItem>();
        berthold = FontHandler.getTypefaceBertholdCondensed();
        nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().locale);

        // Gregg's Code
        spLanguage = mContext.getSharedPreferences(ACTIVITY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // End
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        int type;

        if (mModGroup.getMax() <= 1) {
            // Load Second Layout (Layout with only touch events)
            type = 1;
        } else {
            // Load First Layout (Layout with Increment / Decrement buttons)
            type = 0;
        }

        return type;
    }

    public void setTotalPriceTextView(TextView textViewFromActivity) {
        this.tv_totalPrice = textViewFromActivity;
    }

    public void setTotalPriceTextView2(TextView textViewFromActivity) {
        this.tv_totalPrice2 = textViewFromActivity;
    }

    public void setAvailableOptionsCount(TextView textViewFromActivity) {
        this.tv_availableOptionsCount = textViewFromActivity;
    }

    public void setModifierGroup(ModifierGroup modGroupFromActivity) {
        this.mModGroup = modGroupFromActivity;
    }

    public void setItems(List<ModifierItem> items, String id) {
        mItems = items;
        mModGroupId = id;
    }

    public int countSelected() {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mItems.size(); i++) {
            if (mItems.get(i).isSelected())
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    private List<ModifierItem> getSelectedModifiers() {
        List<ModifierItem> list = new ArrayList<ModifierItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mItems.size(); i++) {
            ModifierItem item = mItems.get(i);
            if (item.isSelected()) {
                item.setGroupId(mModGroupId);
                list.add(item);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public ModifierGroup getModifierGroup() {
        String id = mModGroupId;
        int min = -999;
        int max = -999;
        int free = -999;
        String name = null;
        List<ModifierItem> items = getSelectedModifiers();
        return new ModifierGroup(id, min, max, free, name, items);
    }

    public double getTotalPrice() {
        double ret = 0.0;
        for (ModifierItem item : mItems) {
            ret += (item.getPrice() * item.getQuantity());
        }

        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ModifierItem getItem(int pos) {
        return mItems.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    public void highlightSelected(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        getItem(position).setQuantity(getItem(position).getQuantity() + 1);

        double convertedTotalPrice = 0.0;
        double convertedTotalPrice2 = 0.0;

        try {
            convertedTotalPrice = nf.parse(tv_totalPrice.getText().toString()
                    .substring(0, tv_totalPrice.getText().toString().indexOf(" "))).doubleValue();

            convertedTotalPrice2 = nf.parse(tv_totalPrice2.getText().toString()
                    .substring(0, tv_totalPrice2.getText().toString().indexOf(" "))).doubleValue();

        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        convertedTotalPrice += getItem(position).getPrice();
        convertedTotalPrice2 += getItem(position).getPrice();

        tv_totalPrice.setText(String.format("%.2f " + mContext.getString(R.string.sar_string),
                convertedTotalPrice));
        tv_totalPrice2.setText(String.format("%.2f " + mContext.getString(R.string.sar_string),
                convertedTotalPrice2));

        holder.container.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.modifier_button_toggled);
        holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkout_check);
        holder.price.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    }

    public void unhighlightSelected(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        decrementAvailableOptions(tv_availableOptionsCount);
        getItem(position).setQuantity(getItem(position).getQuantity() - 1);

        double convertedTotalPrice = 0.0;
        double convertedTotalPrice2 = 0.0;

        try {
            convertedTotalPrice = nf.parse(tv_totalPrice.getText().toString()
                    .substring(0, tv_totalPrice.getText().toString().indexOf(" "))).doubleValue();

            convertedTotalPrice2 = nf.parse(tv_totalPrice2.getText().toString()
                    .substring(0, tv_totalPrice2.getText().toString().indexOf(" "))).doubleValue();

        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        convertedTotalPrice -= getItem(position).getPrice();
        convertedTotalPrice2 -= getItem(position).getPrice();

        tv_totalPrice.setText(String.format("%.2f " + mContext.getString(R.string.sar_string), convertedTotalPrice));
        tv_totalPrice2.setText(String.format("%.2f " + mContext.getString(R.string.sar_string), convertedTotalPrice2));

        holder.container.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.modifier_button_untoggled);
        holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#777777"));
        holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkout_add);
        holder.price.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#777777"));
    }

    @Override 
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        final ViewHolder holder;
        savedLanguage = new String(spLanguage.getString("language", ""));
        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            switch (type) {

            case 1: // Modifier Group has only less than or equal to one Available Option
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.modifier_item, parent, false);

                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.container = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modifier_item_container);
                holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modifier_item_image);
                holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modifier_item_name);
                holder.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modifier_item_price);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

                convertView.setTag(R.id.modifier_item_container, holder.container);
                convertView.setTag(R.id.modifier_item_image, holder.img);
                convertView.setTag(R.id.modifier_item_name, holder.name);
                convertView.setTag(R.id.modifier_item_price, holder.price);

                if (getItem(position).getQuantity() > 0) {
                    mItemIndex = position;
                    highlightSelected(holder, position);
                }

                convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Log.d("INDEX", Integer.toString(mItemIndex));

                        // Case 1: The user deselects the item he/she selected.
                        if (getItem(position).getQuantity() > 0) {
                            mItemIndex = -1;
                            Log.d("INDEX 2", Integer.toString(mItemIndex));
                            unhighlightSelected(holder, position);


                        } else {

                        }


                    }

                });

                break;

            case 0: // Modifier Group has more than one Available Option
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.modifier_item_2, parent, false);

                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.container = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modifier_item_container_2);
                holder.incrementImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modifier_item_increment_quantity);
                holder.quantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modifier_item_quantity);
                holder.decrementImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modifier_item_decrement_quantity);
                holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modifier_item_name_2);
                holder.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modifier_item_price_2);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

                convertView.setTag(R.id.modifier_item_container_2, holder.container);
                convertView.setTag(R.id.modifier_item_increment_quantity, holder.incrementImg);
                convertView.setTag(R.id.modifier_item_quantity, holder.quantity);
                convertView.setTag(R.id.modifier_item_decrement_quantity, holder.decrementImg);
                convertView.setTag(R.id.modifier_item_name_2, holder.name);
                convertView.setTag(R.id.modifier_item_price_2, holder.price);

                holder.quantity.setText(Integer.toString(getItem(position).getQuantity()));
                holder.quantity.setTypeface(berthold);

                holder.incrementImg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (isAvailableCountBelowZero(tv_availableOptionsCount)) {
                            displayErrorMessage();
                            return;
                        }

                        int acquiredQuantity = Integer.parseInt(holder.quantity.getText().toString());
                        acquiredQuantity += 1;
                        getItem(position).setQuantity(acquiredQuantity);

                        double convertedTotalPrice = 0.0;
                        double convertedTotalPrice2 = 0.0;

                        try {
                            convertedTotalPrice = nf.parse(tv_totalPrice.getText().toString()
                                    .substring(0, tv_totalPrice.getText().toString().indexOf(" "))).doubleValue();

                            convertedTotalPrice2 = nf.parse(tv_totalPrice2.getText().toString()
                                    .substring(0, tv_totalPrice2.getText().toString().indexOf(" "))).doubleValue();

                        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        convertedTotalPrice += getItem(position).getPrice();
                        convertedTotalPrice2 += getItem(position).getPrice();

                        tv_totalPrice.setText(String.format("%.2f " + mContext.getString(R.string.sar_string),
                                convertedTotalPrice));
                        tv_totalPrice2.setText(String.format("%.2f " + mContext.getString(R.string.sar_string), 
                                convertedTotalPrice2));

                        holder.quantity.setText(Integer.toString(acquiredQuantity));
                    }

                });

                holder.decrementImg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int acquiredQuantity = Integer.parseInt(holder.quantity.getText().toString());
                        if (acquiredQuantity - 1 < 0) {acquiredQuantity = 0;}
                        else {
                            decrementAvailableOptions(tv_availableOptionsCount);
                            acquiredQuantity -= 1;
                            getItem(position).setQuantity(acquiredQuantity);

                            double convertedTotalPrice = 0.0;
                            double convertedTotalPrice2 = 0.0;

                            try {
                                convertedTotalPrice = nf.parse(tv_totalPrice.getText().toString()
                                        .substring(0, tv_totalPrice.getText().toString().indexOf(" "))).doubleValue();

                                convertedTotalPrice2 = nf.parse(tv_totalPrice2.getText().toString()
                                        .substring(0, tv_totalPrice2.getText().toString().indexOf(" "))).doubleValue();

                            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            convertedTotalPrice -= getItem(position).getPrice();
                            convertedTotalPrice2 -= getItem(position).getPrice();

                            tv_totalPrice.setText(String.format("%.2f " + mContext.getString(R.string.sar_string),
                                    convertedTotalPrice));
                            tv_totalPrice2.setText(String.format("%.2f " + mContext.getString(R.string.sar_string),
                                    convertedTotalPrice2));
                        }
                        holder.quantity.setText(Integer.toString(acquiredQuantity));
                    }

                });

                break;

            default:
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.modifier_item, parent, false);

                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.container = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modifier_item_container);
                holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modifier_item_image);
                holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modifier_item_name);
                holder.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modifier_item_price);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

                convertView.setTag(R.id.modifier_item_container, holder.container);
                convertView.setTag(R.id.modifier_item_image, holder.img);
                convertView.setTag(R.id.modifier_item_name, holder.name);
                convertView.setTag(R.id.modifier_item_price, holder.price);

                break;
            }

        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (savedLanguage.equals("ar")) {
            holder.name.setText(getItem(position).getAltName().toUpperCase());
        } else {
            holder.name.setText(getItem(position).getName().toUpperCase());
        }

        holder.price.setText(String.format("%.2f " + mContext.getString(R.string.sar_string), 
                getItem(position).getPrice()));

        holder.name.setTypeface(berthold);
        holder.price.setTypeface(berthold);

        return convertView;
    }

    public void decrementAvailableOptions(TextView tv_count) {
        int availableCount = Integer.parseInt(tv_count.getText().toString());

        if (availableCount + 1 > mModGroup.getMax()) {
            availableCount = mModGroup.getMax();
        } else {
            availableCount += 1;
            if ((mModGroup.getSelectedCount() - 1) < 0) {
                mModGroup.setSelectedCount(0);
            } else {
                mModGroup.setSelectedCount(mModGroup.getSelectedCount() - 1);
            }
        }

        tv_count.setText(Integer.toString(availableCount));
    }

    public boolean isAvailableCountBelowZero(TextView tv_count) {
        boolean isBelowZero = false;
        int availableCount = Integer.parseInt(tv_count.getText().toString());

        if (availableCount - 1 < 0) {
            isBelowZero = true;
        }
        else {
            mModGroup.setSelectedCount(mModGroup.getSelectedCount() + 1);
            tv_count.setText(Integer.toString(availableCount - 1));
        }
        return isBelowZero;
    }

    public void displayErrorMessage() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setTitle("Add-On Limit");
        builder.setMessage("You have exceeded the maximum number of items you can add.");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        RelativeLayout container;
        ImageView img;
        ImageView incrementImg;
        TextView quantity;
        ImageView decrementImg;
        TextView name;
        TextView price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are updating mItemIndex inside few conditions. Can you add below line in getView() method of adapter.
mItemIndex = position;

Comment: The purpose of mItemIndex is to determine the index of the Item whose quantity is greater than 0.